# Parsing a text file into multiple PowerShell objects

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to parse the following text file into PowerShell objects:

```
OBJECT Table 60000 My table 1
{
  OBJECT-PROPERTIES
  {
    Date=09-09-16;
    Time=11:27:31;
    Modified=Yes;
    Version List=;
  }
}

OBJECT Page 60001 My Page
{
  OBJECT-PROPERTIES
  {
    Date=09-09-16;
    Time=11:28:18;
    Modified=Yes;
    Version List=;
  }
}
```

The `OBJECT-PROPERTIES` should be properties of the PowerShell objects. I would also like the text of the object to be included in the object.

I was stating to make some regular expression, but I don't know how to parse all that information into one regular expression.

My object is far longer than 2 objects, but just for the examples sake, its only 2 objects.

**Expected Output:**

```
Object1:
  Type: Table
  Number: 60000
  Name: "My table 1"
  Date: "09-09-16"
  Time: "11:28:18"
  Modified: "Yes"
  "Version List": ""
  Object: "<All of the text in this object>"

Object2:
  Type: Page
  Number: 60001
  Name: "My Page"
  Date: "09-09-16"
  Time: "11:28:18"
  Modified: "Yes"
  "Version List": ""
  Object: "<All of the text in this object>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do following:

```
$txt = "OBJECT Table 60000 My table 1
{
  OBJECT-PROPERTIES
  {
    Date=09-09-16;
    Time=11:27:31;
    Modified=Yes;
    Version List=;
  }
}

OBJECT Page 60001 My Page
{
  OBJECT-PROPERTIES
  {
    Date=09-09-16;
    Time=11:28:18;
    Modified=Yes;
    Version List=;
  }
}"
$expr = "(?<Object>OBJECT (?<Type>\w+) (?<Number>\d+) (?<Name>[\w ]+)\s*{\s*OBJECT-PROPERTIES\s*{\s*Date=(?<Date>[\d-]+);\s*Time=(?<Time>[\d:]+);\s*Modified=(?<Modified>\w+);\s*Version List=(?<Version>[^;]*);\s*}\s*})"
[Regex]::Matches($txt, $expr) | % {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      Type = $_.Groups["Type"].Value;
      Number = $_.Groups["Number"].Value;
      Name = $_.Groups["Name"].Value;
      Date = $_.Groups["Date"].Value;
      Time = $_.Groups["Time"].Value;
      Modified = $_.Groups["Modified"].Value;
      "Version List" = $_.Groups["Version"].Value;
      Object = $_.Groups["Object"].Value
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Type         : Table
Number       : 60000
Name         : My table 1
Date         : 09-09-16
Time         : 11:27:31
Modified     : Yes
Version List : 
Object       : OBJECT Table 60000 My table 1
               {
                 OBJECT-PROPERTIES
                 {
                   Date=09-09-16;
                   Time=11:27:31;
                   Modified=Yes;
                   Version List=;
                 }
               }

Type         : Page
Number       : 60001
Name         : My Page
Date         : 09-09-16
Time         : 11:28:18
Modified     : Yes
Version List : 
Object       : OBJECT Page 60001 My Page
               {
                 OBJECT-PROPERTIES
                 {
                   Date=09-09-16;
                   Time=11:28:18;
                   Modified=Yes;
                   Version List=;
                 }
               }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example whith one regex to capture all properties except the Object itself (you may need a new one for that or work with nested capturing groups):

```
$regex = 'OBJECT\s+(?<type>\w+)\s+(?<number>\d+)\s+(?<name>.+?)\s{.*?Date=(?<date>[^;]+).*?Time=(?<time>.+?);.*?Modified=(?<modified>.+?);.*?Version List=(?<versionlist>.*?);'
$content = Get-Content $scripts.tmp
$matches = [regex]::Matches($content, $regex)
$matches | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Type = $_.Groups['type'].Value
        Number = $_.Groups['number'].Value
        Name = $_.Groups['name'].Value
        Date = $_.Groups['date'].Value
        Time = $_.Groups['time'].Value
        Modified = $_.Groups['modified'].Value
        "Version List" = $_.Groups['versionlist'].Value
    }
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
Type         : Table
Number       : 60000
Name         : My table 1
Date         : 09-09-16
Time         : 11:27:31
Modified     : Yes
Version List : 

Type         : Page
Number       : 60001
Name         : My Page
Date         : 09-09-16
Time         : 11:28:18
Modified     : Yes
Version List :
```

---

**Regex:**

```
OBJECT\s+(?<type>\w+)\s+(?<number>\d+)\s+(?<name>.+?)\s{.*?Date=(?<date>[^;]+).*?Time=(?<time>.+?);.*?Modified=(?<modified>.+?);.*?Version List=(?<versionlist>.*?);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]